# google docs does not display proper document if I change...?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview, google-docs

I own android app, in which I show pdf document in web view using google docs.
My server has that pdf and I load it through below url:

> https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=MYSERVERURLOFPDF

It work fine but when I replaced my pdf on server with another pdf, above url displays old doc and not new one.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache of the browser.